# Zip recursive with excluding some directories

Tags: macos, command-line, unix, zip

I would like to zip the directory but exclude some subdirectories. Let's say I have such structure:

```
directory
   subdirectory 1
   subdirectory 2
     project 1
       html
         directory 1 
         vendor
         node_modules
         ... (other directories)
     project 2
       html
         directory 2 
         vendor
         node_modules
         ... (other directories)
```

I would like to ZIP the whole main directory but I would like to exclude paths like this:

```
subdirectory2/*/html/vendor/**
subdirectory2/*/html/node_modules/**
```

where:

- `*` - is one-level directory
- `**` - is directory with any files and subdirectories

The problem is that those `project 1` and `project 2` are quite dynamic - there are multiple of them. Also notice that `vendor` directories (and also in theory `node_modules`) can be placed in some other places for example in `project 1/html/public/vendor` so I wouldn't like to exclude just `vendor` subdirectory but only specific `vendor` subdirectory that is located exactly in given html directories of projects.

Is it possible to make such complex thing using just `zip` command or maybe some bash script should be written for this?

I'm using MacOS if it makes any difference.

What I've achieved so far is:

```
cd directory && zip test-zip.zip  * -r -T -x */*/html/vendor/** */*/html/node_modules/**
```

It seems it almost works but it creates empty vendor and node modules directories (but not include their content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems solution is:

```
cd directory && 
zip test-zip.zip  * -r -T -x "*/*/html/vendor/" "*/*/html/node_modules/" "*/*/html/vendor/**" "*/*/html/node_modules/**"
```

so I exclude everything in this directories and those directories too and also wrap everything in quotes to be expanded in valid way